# Applying a path as another path's stroke

Tags: wpf, geometry, graphic

In Illustrator, we can use a path as the stroke of another path. Is there any way to do the same thing in WPF: create two path p1, p2 and then use p1 as the stroke of p2?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: I'm using both of them. Is there any way to do this trick in both?